# Rails Activerecord WHERE closest match with booleans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create a type of matchmaking RoR app where users have "interests" as booleans in a table.  I'm trying to match users based on how many booleans they have in common.  Is there some way to do this with a simple WHERE query as opposed to iterating through the entire list and matching them in the controller?

```
+-------+--------+------------+----------+---------+
| user  | tennis | basketball | swimming | running |
+-------+--------+------------+----------+---------+
| test1 | true   | true       | false    | false   |
| test2 | true   | true       | false    | false   |
| test3 | false  | true       | false    | false   |
+-------+--------+------------+----------+---------+
```

So say "test1" was logged in and trying to find someone with similar interests.

"test2" would be a good match and I could find him using user.where("tennis = ? AND basketball = ?",true,true)

but that wouldn't find "test3"

I could also do user.where("tennis = true") but it wouldn't show "test2" as the better match.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, i just added the table and an example of what i want

Comment: what database are you using?